# Is it possible to use an alias for `self` in swift?

Tags: swift

Swift appears to share with python one characteristic of requiring the `class` instance reference to access the members - even inside the class itself. The default in both languages is `self`.  In particular

```
 self.someClassMethod()
```

This is identical between `python` and `swift`.  I also dislike this requirement finding it to be intrusive: it attracts my attention to `self` and away from which method is actually being invoked.   In `python` I reduce (though do not *remove*) the annoyance by using `s` instead:

```
 def someInstanceMethod(s, param1, param2)
```

instead of the standard

```
 def someInstanceMethod(self, param1, param2)
```

Then inside the method I can access other instance methods :

```
   s.someOtherInstanceMethod()
```

I'm not going to fight any battles on this: `PEP` folks will jump up and down about it -but it is more readable to me and others in my team.  Is there any such way to do a shortcut in `swift`?   I noticed `typealias` and tried to use it:

```
 fileprivate let tp = U.tprint  // Any non-critical logging statements will happen with this
```

But then it is necessary to do this:

```
  self.tp("Loaded synthesizer settings")
```

Without the reference to `self` the following error occurs:

```
(162, 25) reference to property 'tp' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
```

I would prefer just

```
  tp("Loaded synthesizer settings")
```

but that is not apparently possible. Can we get *closer* to that - along the lines of `s.<method>` instead of `self.<method>` ?

Comment: `self.someClassMethod()`. This isn't valid Swift inside of an instance method, and isn't required inside a class method (you don't need to include `self.` to call a class method from a class method). Can you show an example with an actual class? Do you mean instance methods? (You don't need to use `self` inside of an instance method to access an instance method)

Comment: I see @matt made an answer so I undeleted this question (snark from others notwithstanding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what the question is, or what you think is the purpose of passing `self` around, so here's a quick summary of the key facts:

- There are instance members and type members (type members are marked `static` or `class`).
- If a method is an instance method, it does not need to say `self` to access instance members.
- If a method is a type method, it does not need to say `self` to access type members.
- If a method is an instance method, it can say `Self` to access type members.
- If a method is a type method, there is no instance so instance members cannot be accessed.

Comment: I'm following what I see from Jetbrains `AppCode` .  Without the reference to `self` it is `(162, 25) reference to property 'tp' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit`

Comment: Yep well that's a special case, namely where you are a level _deeper_ and in an `@escaping` closure. But that, it seems to me, is not what you asked, and has been explained to death on SO already.

Comment: @javadba In that context, the explicit capturing of `self` is done to highlight that it's happening, because that's probably *not* what you want. More likely, you want to capture self weakly.